# Prior probability distribution when we have a single estimate of the mean and no estimate of the variance

Tags: bayesian, prior, information-theory

Say we have some real parameter $p$ we'd like to determine experimentally.  If we have a single estimate of $p$ but no associated uncertainty, what prior probability distribution(s) can/should we use to represent our knowledge?

I can reasonably intuit that it would have to be a distribution with a defined mean but no defined variance (e.g. a t distribution with 1 degree of freedom), but it's not clear to me *which one* we should choose.

I feel like to make progress requires some sort of symmetry argument, a la the Principle of Transformation Groups.  Does anyone have any insight?

Comment: You can assume something like a flat distribution for log-variance, or, something like inverse-$\chi^2$

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal-inverse-gamma_distribution

Comment: The prior distribution should not be determined from the observation of an estimate, it should be chosen *prior* to the observation.

Comment: @Xi'an I'm not sure what you mean - prior to your experiment, you still have some state of existing knowledge that you need to represent as a probability distribution.  Say your prior knowledge is just a value written on a piece of paper with no additional context - how best do we represent that mathematically?

You choose the prior distribution prior to considering *new* observational data that *updates* your belief - but you do not choose it prior to observing *any and all* data.